# Show text in a header tag as it is being typed in an input tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started my journey into the world of React and I love it so far. I finally started to get a grasp of the basics and tried my hand in creating a simple program.
This program simply takes what you are typing in a text box and displays it live in a header tag. I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I get the text to appear in the console, but can't figure out why it isn't displaying in my  tag. Thank you in advance for the help. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
class Header extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "header">
                <h1>Enter Your Name</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Input extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "input_container">
                <input onChange = {this.props.onChange} className = "input_field" type = "text" placeholder = "Name..."></input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        inputValue : ""
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState = ({inputValue: e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Columns />
            <Input
                onChange = {this.onChange}/>
            <h2>{this.state.inputValue}</h2>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect syntax for setState. It is a function and not an object

```
this.setState ({ inputValue: e.target.value });
```

Your code would be

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ""
  };

  onChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input onChange={this.onChange} />
        <h2>{this.state.inputValue}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```